# I often hear "sure is" or "sure do" but do people use "sure" with other kinds of auxiliaries such as "sure won't", "sure can", "sure couldn't", etc.?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [sure](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sure_2)(adv): ​used to emphasize something that you are saying
>
> Boy, it sure is hot.
>
> ‘Amazing view’. ‘**Sure is**.’
>
> I sure hope you are right about that.
>
> That song sure as hell sounds familiar.
>
> He sure looked unhappy.
>
> Working in technology sure beats flipping burgers.
>
> I **sure do** agree with that.

---

I often hear "**sure is**" or "**sure do**" but do people use "**sure**" with other kinds of auxiliaries such as "**sure won't**", "**sure can**", "**sure couldn't**", etc.?

For examples,

> A: I won’t do it for free.
>
> B: Sure won't
>
> A: I can lift this heavy box.
>
> B: Sure can
>
> A: I couldn't do it.
>
> B: Sure couldn't
>
> A: They sang very well.
>
> B: Sure did
>
> A: They have been very nice to us.
>
> B: Sure have
>
> A: Do you cook for me?
>
> B: Sure do
>   ...

Comment: You left out a few: Sure might; Sure should and the negatives: Sure shouldn't/sure wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

All those in the second list sound good to me and I have used and heard similar usages.

In the first list, I have heard and used them all, but I would use "That song sounds familiar as hell" rather than "That song sure as hell sounds familiar" (again, the latter is fine and I have heard the usage plenty of times).